# How to define platform options the same as official platforms in Elastic Beanstalk custom platform

Tags: elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to define the same platform option [as defined in the official platforms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-specific.html#command-options-php) on my custom platform. But, it gives me the error below when I run `ebp create`.

> ERROR: Option definition namespace 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini' is invalid.

My platform.yaml has this;

```
option_definitions:
  - namespace: "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini"
    option_name: "composer_options"
    description: "Some description."
    default_value: ""
```

I also tried with different namespace, but got the same error.

```
namespace: "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:foo:phpini"
```

Is there any way to create options the same as [the official platforms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-specific.html#command-options-php)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the custom platform accepts only the namespace prefixed with `aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:custom:`.

Though I couldn't find the way to mimic options of the official platforms, below worked at least.

```
option_definitions:
  - namespace: "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:custom:php"
    option_name: "composer_options"
    description: "Some description."
    default_value: ""
```